# Правильно ли словосочетание "амальгама культур"?

Tags: грамотная-речь, словосочетания

Недавно услышала это словосочетание в одной из телепрограмм Владимира Соловьёва
"Вечер" или "Воскресный вечер". В передаче разговор шел о российском гражданстве, религии, русском языке, беженцах, толерантности...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вот типичный пример на эту тему: Наше государство состоялось как добровольное объединение десятков наций и национальностей, как **сплав** различных культур и традиций.

А сплав — это (лат.) amalgama, переносное значение — сочетание, смесь чего-л. разнородного. Отсюда и происходит "амальгама культур" и даже "культурная амальгамация". [КУЛЬТУРНАЯ АМАЛЬГАМАЦИЯ | artap.ru](http://www.artap.ru/cult/kultura_amalgama.htm)

**АМАЛЬГАМА,**  [лат. amalgama]. 1. Сплав какого-л. металла с ртутью или раствор металла в ртути. Цинковая а.  // Тонкий слой сплава ртути и серебра, использовавшийся как покрытие внутренней поверхности зеркала. Повредить амальгаму зеркала. 2. **Сочетание, смесь чего-л. разнородного.** А. экономического радикализма и политического консерватизма в чьих-л. взглядах.

Comment: Из признания заимствованного термина "(культурная) амальгамация" (как процесс) ещё не следует корректность не включённого в тот же тезаурус выражения "амальгама культур" (как результат этой самой "амальгамации"), поскольку в русском устоялось выражение "сплав культур", делаещее ненужным альтернативу - она могла возникнуть просто в результате чьей-то попытки пословного перевода （из amalgamation） . "Амальгамация" же используется в контекстах, общих с "ассимиляцией" и "аккультуризацией", вероятно, поэтому и заимствована в буквальной форме. Для обоснования здесь нужны практические примеры.

Answer (score 2):

Такое сочетание возможно (тут Sibylla дает всё исчерпывающе), но насчет того, насколько оно верно в конкретном случае, без достаточного контекста сказать нельзя. У Соловьева в его шоу, к сожалению, следят за политической правильностью куда больше, чем эа языковой. И его "гости" скорее будут доказывать чистоту и "первородность" русской культуры, чем нести в массы тезис о какой-то смеси. Очень возможно, что сказавший подобное просто не знал значения слово "амальгама". Я сам давно его не смотрю, но о его лингвистических ляпах наслышан. 
Впрочем, это все предположения, построенные на весьма косвенных аргументах. Но вы так вопрос поставили, про конкретный случай, а контекста не привели.